# Why azimuth result is wrong for this pyqgis code?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, azimuth

In this code I want to obtain azimuth from a single point to each pixel center, but when run it, in raster created azimuth result for each pixel is wrong, what is correct code?

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr
import numpy as np
import numpy

pntLayer = QgsVectorLayer("E:/Sample_Dataset_Lorestan/Point.shp", "Point", "ogr")
feat = pntLayer.getFeatures().next()
pntxy = feat.geometry().asPoint()

g_NoData_value = -9999

# Open tif file
ds = QgsRasterLayer("E:/Sample_Dataset_Lorestan/subset_a1.tif","subset_a1")
global g_pixelWidth, g_pixelHeight
g_pixelWidth = ds.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
g_pixelHeight = ds.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()

# extent of the layer
ext = ds.extent()
global g_originX ,g_originY
g_originX ,g_originY = (ext.xMinimum(),ext.yMinimum())
cols = ds.width()
rows = ds.height()

# Get Center pixel x y
def pixel2coord(x, y):

  xp = (g_pixelWidth * x) + g_originX + (g_pixelWidth/2)
  yp = (g_pixelHeight * y) + g_originY + (g_pixelHeight /2)
  return(xp, yp)

# Open tif file
ds = gdal.Open("E:/Sample_Dataset_Lorestan/subset_a1.tif")

band1 = ds.GetRasterBand(1)

driver = ds.GetDriver()
outDs = driver.Create("C:/Temp_NoiseOnePoint/Azimuth_lyr.tif", cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)

outBand = outDs.GetRasterBand(1)
outData = numpy.zeros((rows,cols), numpy.float32)

for i in range(0, rows):
  for j in range(0, cols):
    rspnt = pixel2coord(i, j)
    az = pntxy.azimuth(QgsPoint(rspnt[0], rspnt[1]))
    if az < 0.0:
        azim = 360 + az
    else:
        azim = az

    outData[i,j] = azim

# write the data
outBand.WriteArray(outData, 0, 0)

# flush data to disk, set the NoData value and calculate stats

outBand.SetNoDataValue(g_NoData_value)

# georeference the image and set the projection
outDs.SetGeoTransform(ds.GetGeoTransform())
outDs.SetProjection(ds.GetProjection())
outBand.FlushCache()

#outBand = None
outDs = None
```

This picture shows point in green and azimuth raster result in grayscale, min value in white color is 0.5622 and max value in black color in 359.251,It seems that north side is incorrect!

[image]

Comment: I'm really competent concerning the azimuth calculation, but looking globally at the code, shouldn't you use `rspnt = pixel2coord(i,j)` instead of `rspnt = pixel2coord(cols,rows)` ? And the statement `outData[i,j] = azim` shouldn't be indented to be in the two loops ? (because like this it can explain why only the last pixel of `outData` is written)

Comment: Edit to my previous comment : i'm **not** really competent concerning the azimuth calculation !

Comment: Thanks, It's improved and all pixels computed for azimuth, but azimuth result is not correct!

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the erroneous results?